# Generate next rational number in agda

Tags: stream, rational-number, agda

How can i generate the next rational number into 2 integer variables. For example, 
(1,1)
(2,1) (1,2)
(1,3) (3,1)
..
I have the algorithm to generate it :

```
if(n % 2 == d % 2)
{  
  n++;
  if(d > 1) d--;
}
else{
  d++;
  if(n > 1) n--;
}
```

The problem is how to build a dynamic stream in`Agda`a. I will start from (1,1) and then generate the next pair and add it to stream.
Please anyone help.

Answer (score 3):

There is the `iterate` function just like in Haskell:

```
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable
open import Data.Bool using (if_then_else_)
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Stream

next : ℕ × ℕ -> ℕ × ℕ
next (n , m) = if ⌊ n ≟ 1 ⌋ then m + 1 , 1 else pred n , suc m

stream : Stream (ℕ × ℕ)
stream = iterate next (1 , 1)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Vec hiding (take)

test : take 10 stream ≡ (1 , 1) ∷ (2 , 1) ∷ (1 , 2) ∷ (3 , 1) ∷ (2 , 2) ∷ (1 , 3)
                                ∷ (4 , 1) ∷ (3 , 2) ∷ (2 , 3) ∷ (1 , 4) ∷ []
test = refl
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to access the individual element?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369643/accessing-element-from-stream-in-agda