# Accessing element from Stream in agda

Tags: haskell, stream, agda

I have made a stream of (N x N) type. How can i access the individual element of the pair ??

```
genL : ℕ →  Stream (ℕ × ℕ) →  Stream (ℕ × ℕ)
genL k ((x , y) :: xs)  = if ((y * k) lt x) then (x , y) :: (♯ genL k (♭ xs))
                          else genL k (♭ xs)
```

It says there is no constuctor *,* in stream. I have one solution in mind that i will create records of pair then it will works. Apart from that is there any other way to acccess the element.

Comment: Are you looking for [lookup](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Stream.html#2055)? If not, could you start by writing the type of the function you are looking for?

Comment: No,  the stream has element of the form (x , y). I want to access x and y seperately. In the code the second line is not working.

Comment: You can use Data.Product's [projections](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Product.html#525) for that.

Comment: "`It says there is no constuctor , in stream" Import the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is `_∷_` (type `\::` to get `∷`), not `_::_`.

Anyway your definition is not productive and doesn't convince the termination checker.

Comment: No the problem was with "," . That was typo i.e (::). How to convince the termination checker?? This is the reason i have placed NO_TERMINATION_CHECK.

Comment: @ajayv, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. There was a [chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Coinductive.html) about coinduction in the CPDT book.